# MySQL how to know the specific time when an error happens

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 800 million rows. Now I try to add a colume to it:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD mydata BLOB;
```

This command takes a very long time and finally it returns an error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I want to check MySQL log to see what's going on here. However, I don't know when this error happens. Are there anyway I can figure out the specific time when MySQL throw out this Error.

Also, I am interested in why I get this error when doing a long-run query.

Comment: do you run it from the shell with mysql command line?\

Comment: I logged into mysql and ran the command.